# cannot appear in a constant-expression

Tags: c++, constant-expression

In the following c++ program:

```
static const int row = (dynamic_cast<int>(log(BHR_LEN*G_PHT_COUNT)/log(2)));
static const int pht_bits = ((32*1024)/(G_PHT_COUNT * G_PHT_COUNT * BHR_LEN));
unsigned char tab[pht_bits][1<<row];
```

I get the error message **double log(double)’ cannot appear in a constant-expression**.
why am I getting this problem since i have put an integer cast in front? How should i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To you that are downvoting my answer. Tell me that this code does not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double log(double foo)
{
  return 1.0;
}

static const int row = static_cast<int>(log(4)/log(2));

int main(void)
{
  printf("%d\n", row);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Original (changed from (int) to static_cast, not that it matters)

```
static const int row = static_cast<int>(log(BHR_LEN*G_PHT_COUNT)/log(2));
```

Comment: Shouldn't use C style casts in C++. This also won't fix the problem.

Comment: This "answer" doesn't answer the question of why an error is being raised. Alex's answer correctly identifies that the **logically** const value of row is not a **constant expression** and therefore cannot be used as the size of an array. The error may be reported on the wrong line, but this "answer" doesn't provide a solution.

Answer (score 4):

The constant-expression that the compiler is referring to is actually the bounds of the array `tab`.  The dimensions of statically allocated arrays have to be known at compile-time, but the value of `row` can't be determined until runtime, because it is evaluated using a function.

Comment: Upvoted this answer for actually answering the question.